# Can the strong force be expressed as a function of distance between two quarks?

Tags: forces, nuclear-physics, strong-force

I have two very similar questions about the strong force.

1. Can the (non-residual) strong force be expressed as a function of the distance, between two quarks and their color charges? Does it depend on anything else?
2. Can the residual strong force be expressed as a function of distance between two nucleons and does its strength depend on which pair of nucleons interact (p-p, n-n or n-p)?

Thanks for any help with either question.

Comment: The [Cornell potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_potential) is a useful approximation for #1.